# Creating Nested Object Firebase structure

Tags: android, firebase, data-structures, firebase-realtime-database

I'm using Firebase as my database for my Android project. In this project, I have users with minimal data associated with them.

```
    users{
      1234-567-897:{
          Display:"Name",
          Email:"foo@bar.ca"
      },
    ...
```

I made this structure with a basic object User with two local string variables.

My issue is that I now need to add a schedule to each user, which consists of a list of Events, each event with it's own information(Start time, End time, etc.)

I understand that my structure would probably look something like this:

```
users{
  1234-567-897:{
      Display:"Name",
      Email:"foo@bar.ca",
      Schedule:{
          event1:{
               name:"Meeting",
               startTime:1,
               endTime:2
          },
          event2:{...}
      },
      Sschedule2:{...}
  },
```

But I have no idea how to go about creating this type of structure with Firebase. I was initially going to use an ArrayList to hold the objects of Schedules and Events but after reading the Firebase documentation, it looks like they don't support ArrayList storing. An alternative to this that I was considering was to create a separate table of schedules and reference them with uids.

Appreciate any advise regarding creating this structure, thanks!

Comment: I've read [Firebase Structure Data](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/structure-data) but it doesn't specific how to create those structures

Answer (score 5, accepted):

These seem to be the minimal classes needed for your data:

```
public class Event {
  public String name;
  public Long startTime;
  public Long endTime;
}

public class User { 
  public String Display;
  public String Email;
  public Map<String, Event> Schedule;
}
```

The `Schedule` is a map, where the keys are `event1` and `event2`.

I didn't add `Schedule2` because its type is unspecified.

Comment: This assumes all events in the schedule have different names.

Comment: I think the Map object was what I'm missing, thanks!

Comment: @JamesB: for Firebase Database this is the recommended structured for list-like structures. See https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/lists-of-data#append_to_a_list_of_data and https://firebase.googleblog.com/2014/04/best-practices-arrays-in-firebase.html

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen My comment is more Java-specific than any library/database. If the key for the map is the name of the event, two different events with the same name will overwrite each other when stored in Schedule. If the key is unique per event then my initial comment can be ignored.

Comment: The `Schedule` map in the above would be keyed on the node name in the JSON structure. So `event1` and `event2` in the above sample, but in most Firebase Database projects they would be [auto-generated push IDs](firebase.googleblog.com/2015/02/the-2120-ways-to-ensure-unique_68.html).