# Hashmaps in POJO to cater for nested Firebase structure

Tags: android, firebase, data-structures, firebase-realtime-database, pojo

Coding my first app with Firebase and trying to get a nested structure into one POJO as I am going to display everything on the same screen, but not having success in retrieving the inner structure.
Here's the snapshot:

```
{ 
key = -KIqtlY8VQFCuYmi-fWc, 
value = {
    tripName=Paris in June, 
    cityId=paris, 
    arrivalDate=2310943,
    duration=4, 
    days={
        day1={
            -KpMhSTQABFhbBHri0VU={
                keyItem=-KGYdK_RIc3Whm5Vp5WM, 
                orderItem=99, 
                typeItem=att
            },
        day2={
            -KpMhSTQABFhbBHri0AB={
                keyItem=-KGYdK_RIc3Whm5Vp5WM, 
                orderItem=99, 
                typeItem=att
            }
        }
    } 
    } 
}
```

Here are my classes:

```
@IgnoreExtraProperties
public class Trip {
    @Exclude
    private String id;
    private String cityId;
    private String tripName;
    private long arrivalDate;
    private int duration;
    private Map<String, DayTrip> days; // = new HashMap<String, DayTrip>();

    public Trip() {
    }

    public Trip(String cityId, String tripName, long arrivalDate, int duration, Map<String, DayTrip> days) {
        this.cityId = cityId;
        this.tripName = tripName;
        this.arrivalDate = arrivalDate;
        this.duration = duration;
        this.days = days;
    }


    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public String getCityId() {
        return cityId;
    }

    public String getTripName() {
        return tripName;
    }


    public long getArrivalDate() {
        return arrivalDate;
    }


    public int getDuration() {
        return duration;
    }

    public Map<String, DayTrip> getDays() {
        return days;
    }
}

public class DayTrip {
    private Map<String, ScheduledItem> scheduledItems; // = new HashMap<String, ScheduledItem>();

    public DayTrip() {
    }

    public DayTrip(String notes, Map<String, ScheduledItem> scheduledItems) {
        this.scheduledItems = scheduledItems;
    }

    public Map<String, ScheduledItem> getScheduledItems() {
        return scheduledItems;
    }
}

public class ScheduledItem {

    private String keyItem;
    private String typeItem;
    private int orderItem;

    public ScheduledItem() {

    }

    public ScheduledItem(String keyItem, String typeItem, int orderItem) {
        this.keyItem = keyItem;
        this.typeItem = typeItem;
        this.orderItem = orderItem;
    }

    public void setKeyItem(String keyItem) {
        this.keyItem = keyItem;
    }

    public void setTypeItem(String typeItem) {
        this.typeItem = typeItem;
    }

    public void setOrderItem(int orderItem) {
        this.orderItem = orderItem;
    }

    public String getKeyItem() {
        return keyItem;
    }
    public String getTypeItem() {
        return typeItem;
    }
    public int getOrderItem() {
        return orderItem;
    }
    @Exclude
    public Map<String, Object> toMap() {
        HashMap<String, Object> result = new HashMap<>();
        result.put("keyItem", keyItem);
        result.put("typeItem", typeItem);
        result.put("orderItem", orderItem);

        return result;
    }
}
```

Here's the code I'm using to inspect the object:

```
    mUserRef1 = mFirebaseRef.child("trips").child(getUid());

    mUserRef1.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            for (DataSnapshot snap: dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                Trip trip = snap.getValue(Trip.class);
                for (Map.Entry<String, DayTrip> day: trip.getDays().entrySet()){
                    for (Map.Entry<String, ScheduledItem> item: day.getValue().getScheduledItems().entrySet()) {
                        Log.d(TAG, item.getValue().getKeyItem());
                    }
                }

            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
```

The first map is retrieved but not the second one. It never gets into the most inner for each.

Comment: At what is `mUserRef1` pointing?

Comment: Pointing to all trips created by a specific user.

Comment: Can you update this in your code?

Comment: @AlexMamo There. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Please use this code:

```
DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
DatabaseReference uidRef = rootRef.child("trips").child(getUid());
ValueEventListener eventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        String tripName = dataSnapshot.child("tripName").getValue(String.class);
        String cityId = dataSnapshot.child("cityId").getValue(String.class);
        String arrivalDate = dataSnapshot.child("arrivalDate").getValue(String.class);
        String duration = dataSnapshot.child("duration").getValue(String.class);

        for(DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.child("days").getChildren()) {
            String keyItem = ds.child("keyItem").getValue(String.class);
            String orderItem = ds.child("orderItem").getValue(String.class);
            String typeItem = ds.child("typeItem").getValue(String.class);
            Log.d("TAG", keyItem + " / " + orderItem + " / " + typeItem);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {}
};
uidRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(eventListener);
```

This code will work if you'll remove the pushed key from the days node. There are two childs when only one is needed. You can either remove the number of the day, let's say day1, day 2 and so on, either the pushed key -KpMhSTQABFhbBHri0VU, -KpMhSTQABFhbBHri0AB.

Your days node should look like this:

```
days={
    day1={
            keyItem=-KGYdK_RIc3Whm5Vp5WM, 
            orderItem=99, 
            typeItem=att,
    day2={
            keyItem=-KGYdK_RIc3Whm5Vp5WM, 
            orderItem=99, 
            typeItem=att,
    }
}
```

or

```
days={
    -KpMhSTQABFhbBHri0VU={
            keyItem=-KGYdK_RIc3Whm5Vp5WM, 
            orderItem=99, 
            typeItem=att,
    -KpMhSTQABFhbBHri0AB={
            keyItem=-KGYdK_RIc3Whm5Vp5WM, 
            orderItem=99, 
            typeItem=att,
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this @AlexMamo but I what I want to know is how to load the entire structure into a POJO. Besides there are several ScheduleItems for each day.  I am looking for something like this but with an additional level:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42893231/creating-nested-object-firebase-structure

Comment: No, I haven't. :-(