# FirebaseRecyclerAdapter but Failed to convert value of type java.util.HashMap to String?

Tags: java, android, firebase-realtime-database, firebaseui

Trying to create FirebaseRecyclerAdapter that retrieve data all data from object class , but i get the error "Failed to convert value of type java.util.HashMap to String"
here is my code :

```
public class Match {


    private Map<String, Object> name;
    private Map<String, Object> desc;

    public Map<String, Object> getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public Map<String, Object> getDesc() {
        return desc;
    }

    public Match(){} //even with /without this guy
}


public class MatchHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    private final TextView mNameField;
    private final TextView mMessageField;

    public MatchHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        mNameField = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(android.R.id.text1);
        mMessageField = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(android.R.id.text2);
    }

    public void setName(Map<String, Object> name) {
        mNameField.setText((CharSequence) name);
    }

    public void setDesc(Map<String, Object> desc) {
        mMessageField.setText((CharSequence) desc);
    }
}



public class SportActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    final FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_sport);

 DatabaseReference ref = database.getReference("myApp/sportActivity"); //with this guy i get the mentioned error

        //if use         DatabaseReference ref = database.getReference("myApp/sportActivity/Match");
        //i get in the log cat ,error W/ClassMapper: No setter/field for name1,name2 ,desc1,desc2 ...etc    
         RecyclerView matches = (RecyclerView) findViewById(recycle_viewer);
        matches.setHasFixedSize(true);
       matches.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));


        FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Match, MatchHolder> mAdapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Match, MatchHolder>(
                Match.class,
                android.R.layout.two_line_list_item,
                MatchHolder.class,
                ref) {
            @Override
            public void populateViewHolder(MatchHolder holder, Match match, int position) {
                holder.setName(match.getName());
                holder.setDesc(match.getDesc());
            }
        };

        matches.setAdapter(mAdapter);



    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        FirebaseRecyclerAdapter mAdapter = null;
        mAdapter.cleanup();
    }


    }
```

i could not upload a pic of my database ,however ,the structure is :
myApp/sportActivity/
here is the Json of sportActivity:

```
"sportActivity" : {
      "Match" : {
        "desc" : {
          "des3" : "desc3",
          "desc2" : "desc2"
        },
        "name" : {
          "name1" : "name1",
          "name2" : "name2"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Instead of trying to upload a picture, edit your question to include the actual minimal JSON of your database. You can get this by clicking the "Export JSON" link in your [Firebase Database console](https://console.firebase.google.com/project/_/database/data).

Comment: Could you show more code ?

Comment: @KeLiuyue all the required code been provided .

Comment: I could see the `HashMap`  in your code .

Comment: @KeLiuyue in order to avoid misleading comments ,please comment me only if you have a suggestion on how to solve the problem ?

Comment: Sorry for you question .@s.u

Comment: Indicate when you cross-post please: https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android/issues/934

Comment: @Frank van Puffelen why would you through such words ?

Comment: Both Sam (on Github) and I (here) now spent time trying to help you on the exact same problem, without seeing what the other already explained or didn't. One of us could instead have spent that time helping someone else. While your chances of being helped increased by cross-posting without any indication, the total help to the community decreased.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen can not make me feel guilty, Sam's only help to me was the direction of posting here instead  of GitHub as it was not a bug in code ,instead of trying to be so hard on me for no reason you could spend time helping the community !

Comment: Both Sam and I tried to also help you by providing answers, in return we ask that you indicate when you cross-post across sites.

Answer (score 1):

The `Match` object has the following structure:

```
{
  "desc" : {
    "des3" : "desc3",
    "desc2" : "desc2"
  },
  "name" : {
    "name1" : "name1",
    "name2" : "name2"
  }
}
```

The Java class you're using to read this data into is:

```
public class Match {
   private String name; 
   private String desc;

   public Match() { }

   public String getName() { return name; }
   String getDesc() { return desc; }
}
```

These don't match: your Java class says that `desc` is a string, but it's actually a nested JSON object. Since there's no class for that nested JSON object, Firebase will read it as a `Map<String, Object`. And since  your `desc` property is a String, it's an incompatible type and that leads to a class cast exception.

To learn more about how to model a nested object, have a look at my answer here: [Creating Nested Object Firebase structure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42893231/creating-nested-object-firebase-structure)

**Update**: Applied to your JSON, the minimal Java class seems to be:

```
public class Match {
    private Map<String, Object> name;
    private Map<String, Object> desc;

    public Map<String, Object> getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public Map<String, Object> getDesc() {
        return desc;
    }
}
```

Comment: say have added the map like this to the Match class , what modification should be mad to other class ?

Comment: The answer I linked contains a complete minimal example of what you need to do. Edit your question to show what you did and I'll have a look.

Comment: i have added the map to my Match Class , now i still get the same error unless which i think and do not know how to do there must be a modification to the rest of classes/re structure?

Comment: You **added** a `getMatchMap()`, but there is no property `matchMap` in your JSON so that will never get populated. And you left your `desc` and `name` properties defined as `String`, which doesn't match your JSON.

Comment: ,now i get this guy com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseException: Can't convert object of type java.lang.String to type com.myapp.packagename.Match

Comment: That sounds like a different problem again. Since you didn't share the code that actually reads (attaches a listener, or creates an adapter), it's hard to say where it comes from.